# How do I rename top level Classname during JAXB code generation using XJC?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to generate some beans from several xsd's. Unfortunately they all have the same root element. I have successfully created a xjc bindings file for renaming sub-elements but cannot find a way to select the root node to change that.

I tried the following but get the error: [ERROR] XPath evaluation of "/" needs to result in an element.

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:com.fnf="http://www.fnf.com/xes">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="transcode-submit.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

    <jxb:bindings node="/">
        <jxb:property name="Newname"/>                                     
    </jxb:bindings>

  </jxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:com.fnf="http://www.fnf.com/xes">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="transcode-submit.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

  <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='OLDROOTNAME']">
      <jxb:class name="NEWNAME"/>                                     
   </jxb:bindings>
```