# XJC compilation - root element is same in two schemas

Tags: jaxb, cxf, cxf-xjc-plugin

I have two xsd files with same root element name.Ideally,it is preferred to have two unique names in these 2 xsd files.

### PROBLEM FACED:

If I want the JAXB to create classes with unique identifictaion ,how can we acheive through external binding?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5157560/1989025) other SO question.

Comment: Thanks Almir,But,one small question based on the link you suggested.Does it mean that 'node="//xs:element[@name='OLDROOTNAME']"' is always a 'complex type' if you want to create a class with desired name?

Comment: You can rename attributes as well as complex types. Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp149287), section "Fixing Collide Example" for a detailed example

Comment: <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true" localScoping="toplevel"> -----what does this do in xjc compilation?